# How to split a string by comma and white space

Tags: regular-expressions

I have a string, I want to separate it by ',' and white Space, if it has any.

**This is what I have done :**

```
  String s = 'Donate, Pricing,BOM';

    List<String> stringList = s.split(",[\s]*"); 

    system.debug('Check'+stringList);

Check(Donate,  Pricing, BOM)
```

But I want Check(Donate, Pricing, BOM)

I am getting error :

> Invalid string literal ',[\s]*'. Illegal character sequence '\s' in
>   string literal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
String x = 'a, b,c';
system.debug(x.split('[,]{1}[\\s]?'));
```

--KC

Comment: What {1} does here ?

Comment: Specifies that you are searching for one and only one instance of a comma.

Comment: What if you want to add single quotes to each split item?

Answer (score 2):

The square brackets (Character Classes) are not necessary for the pattern. Also using the `*` (zero or more times) operator over `?` (once or not at all) operator will allow for the scenario where more than one space might be after the comma.

```
String x = 'a, b,c,  d';
String[] result = x.split(',\\s*');

System.assertEquals(4, result.size());
System.assertEquals('a', result[0]);
System.assertEquals('b', result[1]);
System.assertEquals('c', result[2]);
System.assertEquals('d', result[3]);
```