# comma seperated field to apex list items

Tags: apex, visualforce, list, data

I Have a text field wich contains data like 123, 234, 345, 456, 567. I now want to put this data in a list.
It needs some sort of loop that gets the first 3 digits on the left side of the comma. I can't figure out how to do this. any tips?

Comment: you can go through this link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48684/how-to-split-a-string-by-comma-and-white-space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this.

```
String commaValue = '123, 234, 345, 456, 567';
List<String> splitted = commaValue.split(',');
System.debug(splitted.size()); 
//Result would be 5
```

You can convert it to integer using valueOf method.